# How to use large numbers in angular 5+?

Tags: angular, typescript, linq-to-twitter

I am using angular 5 with .Netcore 2.0. I am using the API controller to process tweets(LinqToTwitter). The tweets comes through my typescript from the controller all fine apart from the `statusID` which is 19 digits long.

The `statusID` should be:
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX573

but it is coming through to type script as:
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX600

API controller:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<Search> GetAllTweetsByNamePost([FromBody] SearchQuery searchQuery)
{
    searchVal = searchQuery.Name;
    Twitter twit = new Twitter();
    twit.Initialise();
    var t = await twit.Fetch(searchVal, 50, true, SearchType.Search);
    return t[0];
}
```

When I check the `Status` ID in the controller it shows the correct ID but But the time it gets to the TS `statusID` is different and there is a pattern in the numbers.

the first 16 digits are correct and the last 3 increments by 100 e.g.

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX100
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX200
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX300

In the Api controller I am using the `LinqToTwitter` `Status` `object`. The type of the property in the `Status` `object` is  public `ulong SinceID { get; set; }` and I have set the property Of the TS Model is `statusID: any;`

```
getSocialDataTwitter(searchQuery) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post<LeftOperatorPaneltwitter>(this.baseUrl + 'api/OperationData/GetAllTweetsByNamePost', '{"Name":"' + searchQuery + '"}', { headers }).subscribe(result => {
      this.tweets = result;
      result.statuses.forEach(search => {
        console.log(search.statusID + ' This is my Status ID');
      })
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
```

Comment: Why not use strings ?

Comment: I was about to suggest the same thing :P

Comment: I have tried strings. Same result.

Comment: Yes, the console shows the wrong numbers. All the Other data are fine except the `statusID` which has 19 digits.

Comment: Yes!, Network>GetAllTweetsByNamePost> Preview. has the wrong values aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript cannot handle numbers of such a length. According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), the maximum safe integer value is: `9007199254740991`. I'd suggest representing your ID as a `string`.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, the value was way too long because I was using the LinqToTwitter Model which has a property of ulong. I created a minified version of my `Search` Model and changed the `statusID` to string. I realise I had to changed the type on the Api side because someone had suggested in the comments above to check the data in the network tab and the data was wrong there too.

Comment: @Decoder94 Yeah. That was my suggestion. I removed the question the moment I realised JavaScript has this limitation.